# Using variable(objects) inside a mysql.execute() statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

The following code for my python project seems not to work

```
import mysql.connector as sql  
    cxn=sql.connect(user='adithyan',password='vinod123',database='workout2')  
    cursor=cxn.cursor()  
    while True:
        try:
            l=[ ]  
            studentid =int(input("Please enter your student_id"))  
            a = 'select * from student_info where Student_ID = %studentid'  
            cursor.execute(a)    
            for i in cursor:  
                l.append(i)   
         except:    
            print("Student_id not found try again")
```

The MySQL connectivity has no problem and also the select statement has no problem (i.e the query run is correct when I independently run inside the python) **but**
it seems I can't use my variable from python inside the SQL query. Also, please suggest
any other alternatives if possible!!

Cheers,
Adithyan

P.S:-This is **NOT** for my homework. For studying MySQL I watch YouTube, During my coding sessions, I thought of doing a simple python project. That's when I encountered this bug

Comment: Please note in the "try" statement after ' l.append(i) ' we could use a ' print(l) ' statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity depends on the type of the input given. If you're sure about the type of input, ie, if it's a string or number, you can directly adopt **Khan's Answer**, with better string formatting. Few examples:

```py
# Method 1(f-string) - if a number
a = f'select * from student_info where Student_ID = {studentid}'
# if string
a = f"select * from student_info where Student_ID = '{studentid}'"
```

Else, if the type of the input given us dynamic, ie, can be either of string or number, here is a one liner suitable for this:

```py
a = 'select * from student_info where Student_ID = ' + (studentid if studentid.isnumeric() else "'"+studentid+"'")
```

The above is possible only if no other conditions aren't given, ie, only if concatenation doesn't produce unnecessary complications.
You can also do is using f-string:

```py
a = f'''select * from student_info where Student_ID = {(studentid if studentid.isnumeric() else "'"+studentid+"'")}'''
```

Comment: Can you suggest a book or a video from which I can learn further about this connectivity???

Comment: @Python-Freelancer wdym connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

In case of `studentid` being a string, your sql statement (or `a` variable) should be like:

```
a =''' select * from student_info where Student_ID = '{studentid}'; '''.format(
   studentid=studentid
)
```

In case its an integer (or a numerical value), you don't need any quotes around `{studentid}`:

```
a =''' select * from student_info where Student_ID = {studentid}; '''.format(
   studentid=studentid
)
```

Comment: This can be vulnerable to SQL injection if input is not properly escaped.

Comment: Yes. This is a valid statement.